DNS related. SAME IP. A and PTR records
I have to create 2 'A' records and both the records are pointing to the same IP address.
Now if multiple A records pointing to same IP can be created why is it not recommended to create PTR records where same IP address is pointing to different host names.
If I create two A records (pointing to same IP) I will have to create its corresponding PTR records as well, correct? So both the URLs can be accessible without any network/other issues.
This is a theoretical question.
